# Can't get the source tab back in VS express

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I know that this may sound like a stupid question, but I've googled, and can't seem to find a decent solution anywhere. In Visuals express, I accidently pressed the "X" in the upper-right corner of the tab where I could edit the code, and now I can't get it back... I'm working with a console application in C#. Help would be appreciated.

I'm stuck here: http://prntscr.com/1tzcgv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself:
**View > Solution Explorer > *name*.cs**